# Get Select Tag Value not Option Value jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, drop-down-menu, laravel-blade

Im working on a Laravel Blade Templating and I have this select dropdown,

```
<select class="form-control" name="{{ $value->columnheader }}" id="{{ $value->columnheader }}" value="{{ $value->costperlead }}" disabled>
   <option value="">---</option>
   <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
   <option value="No">No</option>
  <option value="Possibly">Possibly</option>
</select>
```

In case they choose yes on the options given, how can I get the value of the select dropdown based from it's id? This value `value="{{ $value->costperlead }}"`

Thanks!

Comment: `value` is not a `<select>` attribute. [attr reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Attributes)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

value is associated property for select element. `.val()` will return  the selected option value and not value attribute added in select element.

You can use `.attr()` attribute name to get the attribute value:

```
$('.form-control').attr('value');
```

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ch59b1eu/)**

However i would suggest you to use `data-value` instead of `value` for having custom attribute. and then get it using:

```
 $('.form-control').data('value');
```

Comment: I have a lot of input fields with class="form-control", I need to get it by id. Thanks

Comment: just change the selector to : `$('#select_id_here').attr('value');`

Comment: $('#select_id_here').attr('value'); I think it will get the option values not the value that I tag on the select dropdown? I will try your data-value instead. Thanks :)

Comment: fiddle shows the demo that `.attr('value')` get the attribute value from select and not from option. check it out

Comment: Oh, I didn't notice, it's working now :) I though it will select the value based from the dropdown selected. I missed that. Thanks :) will select this as answer :)